# Permanently delete a Google Business Account

Tags: google-my-business

Let's say I have a business account attached to my main Google account. I know how to [remove](https://support.google.com/business/answer/6085345?hl=en) it, but the confirmation page made me really unconfident about the process.

Basically, I need to know if I remove the business account, does the main account remain untouched?

Comment: Are you talking about Google apps

Comment: What's the message?

Comment: @AlE. Something about the process being irreversible. It doesn't say nothing about the business account, which gives me the feeling that the whole account will be deleted.

Comment: It'd be much better if you could [edit] the _exact_ text into your question.

Comment: It's look to me that by "my main Google account" the OP is referring to a consumer account and by "business account" the OP referring to an alternative address but can't be sure until the OP clarify this in the question. Bear in mind that a single account could have several email addresses and that they could be changed.

Comment: Just read a bit about "Google Business accounts" -> [About business account - Google My Business Help](https://support.google.com/business/answer/6085326?hl=en). There it says that a business account is like a shared folder, so it looks to me that the "main account" should be "untouched" but I your account is important, then you should ask to Google My Business support. In the Google My Business Help center there are links to the official help forum and to the contact options with the official support.